# unable to display data on broswer using spring hibernate.below is my code and output

Tags: spring, hibernate

Unable to display data on broswer using spring hibernate.below is my code and output..

Class: CustomerController

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.controller;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.DAO.CustomerDAO;
import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Customer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomer(Model theModel){
        List<Customer> theCustomers = customerDAO.getCustomers();

        theModel.addAttribute("customers", theCustomers);

        System.out.println(theCustomers);

        return "list-customer";
    }
}
```

Class: CustomerDAO Implementation

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.DAO;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Customer;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        Session getSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query<Customer> theCustomers = getSession.createQuery("from Customer", Customer.class);

        List<Customer> customers = theCustomers.getResultList();

        return customers;
    }
}
```

Class: Customer mapping to database

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```

jsp page..

```
     <table>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>

            <!-- loop over and print our customers -->
            <c:forEach var="tempCustomer" items="${customers}">

                <tr>
                    <td> ${tempCustomer.firstName} </td>
                    <td> ${tempCustomer.lastName} </td>
                    <td> ${tempCustomer.email} </td>
                </tr>

            </c:forEach>

        </table>
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using an old version of jstl where expressions must be called witch `<c:out/>` tag.

Try the following in your jsp

```html
<td><c:out value="${tempCustomer.firstName}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${tempCustomer.lastName}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${tempCustomer.email}" /></td>
```